# How to calculate with dates in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, hcl

Aaccording to [Terraform documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/consumption_budget_subscription) I am trying to calculate a max. start date in Terraform, which has to be the first day of the month within the next 12 monthes.

I found [this post](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/specifying-a-date-in-the-future/8359/2) which let me start to implement it like the following example:

```
  locals {
    current_time           = timestamp()
    today                  = formatdate("YYYY-MM-DD", local.current_time)
    max_start_date         = formatdate("YYYY-MM-DD", timeadd(local.today, "8640h")) # max. 360 days 
    ...
```

But now I'm lost. I need to create the maximum start date which has to be the first day of the month within a 12 month time range ...

Any Ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what the max_start_date should be for different dates?

Comment: Terraform doesn't have much support for date calculations. You are probably better off calculating that outside of Terraform and passing it in as a variable. Also it's not clear at all what you mean by "the first day of the month within the next 12 months".

Comment: @MarkB there is a lot we can do with the provided functions... like for example the first day of next month can be done: `timeadd(formatdate("YYYY-MM-01'T'00:00:00Z", timestamp()), "744h")` ... we just need clarification on the question

Comment: the 8640 Hours is 360 Days (a year?!?). maybe the ask is for the first day of the month a year from today

Answer (score 6):

There is a lot we can do with the provided functions:

- formatdate https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/formatdate.html
- timeadd https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/timeadd.html

for example if I wanted to get the first day of the current month I could do:
`formatdate("YYYY-MM-01", timestamp())`
output of that > "2021-08-01"

Now if we want to add to that we need to format it in a way that will work for timeadd:
`timeadd(formatdate("YYYY-MM-01'T'00:00:00Z", timestamp()), "24h")`
output of that > "2021-08-02T00:00:00Z"

---

From your code:
`formatdate("YYYY-MM-DD", timeadd(local.today, "8640h")) # max. 360 days`
if all you just need is the first day, just do `"YYYY-MM-01"`
also keep in mind that 360 days is not a full year:
https://www.google.com/search?q=hours+in+a+year

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [time_rotating](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/time/latest/docs/resources/rotating) resource, set `rotation_years=1`, then import it as existing on the first day of the current month.